# App writes to ".log.1" file instead of ".log" file after running logrotate

Tags: ubuntu, logging, logrotate

After force running `logrotate`, my app keeps writing to `my_app.log.1` (the old log that should be archived later) instead of `my_app.log`.

This make `my_app.log` an empty file, therefore `logrotate` runs without any effect. And `my_app.log.1` keep growing to gigabytes.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04. My app is a Node.js app using [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2). Following is my logrotate configuration:

```
"/var/log/my_app/*.log" {
  daily
  size 50M
  rotate 10
  missingok
  compress
  delaycompress
  notifempty
}
```

I know I put `notifempty` there, but why is `my_app.log.1` written to in the first place?

Comment: If the application keeps the log file open while it is running, it is not affected by the file name being changed. It continues to write in the file. `logrotate` can be configured (in a `postrotate` script) to restart the application (or send it a `HUP` signal, if the application responds to it) after it renames the files. There are examples in the documentation.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I finally figured out how to solve the problem.

This was because the log file was being written by `pm2`. `logrotate` changed its name to `my_app.log.1` and created new `my_app.log` file, but `pm2` did not care about this and kept writing to `my_app.log.1`.

I solved the problem by replacing the `notifempty` option by `copytruncate` and then restarted `pm2`. After fixing, `notifempty` can be added back but I do not really need it.

See the [`logrotate` reference](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/logrotate/logrotate.8.en.html) for more information. Hope this will help other folks getting a similar problem.

Comment: There is a small problem with copytruncate. While the file is being copied and truncated, some amount of data will be lost. How do you solve this?

Comment: I think a better solution is to use postrotate script to restart the pm2 processes but adds additional complexity.